# 1064 MYSQL Error distance formula

Tags: mysql, distance

I have this query:

```
SELECT
  *,
  SQRT(POW( 69.1 * ( latitude - ) , 2 )
  + POW( 69.1 * ( - longitude ) * COS( latitude /57.3 ) ,2) ) AS distance
FROM
  properties
HAVING
  distance < 5
ORDER BY
  distance
```

but when I try to run it, I get this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use ;

What I am doing wrong? It is not working in MYSQL 5.0, but it works fine in MYSQL 5.5.

Comment: I don't believe this expression: `( latitude - )` is valid in any version of MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
SELECT
  *,
  SQRT(POW( 69.1 * ( latitude  ) , 2 )
  + POW( 69.1 * (  longitude ) * COS( latitude /57.3 ) ,2) ) AS distance
FROM
  properties
HAVING
  distance < 5
ORDER BY
  distance
```

This should return the result-set you want.
Let me know, if it doesn't.

-- seekers01